# OpenWrt (Linino) + uHTTPd + PHP 5.4 - how to add Phar and Filter module to PHP

Tags: php, filter, arduino, openwrt, phar

I am struggling with adding `Phar` and `Filter` module to `PHP`, under my `uHTTPd` server on `OpenWrt (Linino)`. Can I ask for some advice?

```
My system settings:
Linux Arduino 3.8.3
PHP Version 5.4.17
```

I was able successfully install other modules like `curl`, simply by running `opkg` command

```
opkg install php5-mod-curl
```

But when trying the same with `Phar` or `Filter` there's no luck, these packages don't exist.

```
root@Arduino:~# opkg install php5-mod-phar
Unknown package 'php5-mod-phar'.
```

Do I need to rebuild my `php` to include them (if so, how?) or is there a simpler way of doing this?
Can anyone help me and point me to the right direction?

Also, this is part of the output from my `phpinfo()`

```
Configure Command
'./configure' '--target=mips-openwrt-linux' '--host=mips-openwrt-linux' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--program-suffix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--localstatedir=/var' '--mandir=/usr/man' '--infodir=/usr/info' '--disable-nls' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--disable-rpath' '--disable-debug' '--without-pear' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5' '--disable-short-tags' '--with-zlib=/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-zlib-dir=/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--disable-phar' '--enable-cli' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-calendar=shared' '--enable-ctype=shared' '--with-curl=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--with-gettext=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libintl-full' '--enable-dom=shared' '--enable-exif=shared' '--enable-ftp=shared' '--with-gd=shared' '--without-freetype-dir' '--with-jpeg-dir=/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-png-dir=/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--without-xpm-dir' '--without-t1lib' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--disable-gd-jis-conv' '--with-gmp=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-hash=shared' '--with-iconv=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libiconv-stub' '--enable-json=shared' '--with-ldap=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-ldap-sasl=/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-mysql=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-mysqli=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-kerberos=no' '--with-openssl-dir=/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-pcntl=shared' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-pgsql=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-session=shared' '--enable-shmop=shared' '--enable-simplexml=shared' '--enable-soap=shared' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--with-sqlite=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--with-sqlite3=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-tokenizer=shared' '--enable-xml=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared,/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr' '--enable-zip=shared' '--disable-filter' '--enable-libxml' '--with-libxml-dir=/home/build/builddir/all-in-one/dogstick/trunk/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include/libxml2' '--with-system-tzdata'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Build PHP with Filter support:**

```
make menuconfig
```

**select:**

```
language/php/PHP5 filter support
```

**rebuild:**

```
make package/feeds/packages/php5/compile
```